# How to compress pandas DataFrame into a dictionary with unique keys and listed values?

Tags: python, pandas, list

I have the following example pandas DataFrame, whereby there are two columns, `Name` and `Age`:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [['Alex',10],['Bob',12],['Barbara',25], ['Bob',72], 
    ['Clarke',13], ['Clarke',13], ['Destiny', 45]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['Name','Age'], dtype=float)

print(df)
      Name   Age
0     Alex  10.0
1      Bob  12.0
2  Barbara  25.0
3      Bob  72.0
4   Clarke  13.0
5   Clarke  13.0
6  Destiny  45.0
```

My end goal is to create a dictionary, whereby each key is the Name and each value is a list of `Ages` associated with that `Name`.

So, the ending dictionary would be

```
final_result = {"Alex":[10], "Bob":[12, 72], "Barbara":[25], "Clarke":[13], "Destiny":[45]}
```

My approach:

I could try iterating through the dataframe to create the lists, and rename the column:

```
for name in df.Name.unique():
    list_attributes = []
    for i in df.loc[df.Age == name].Age.unique()
        list_attributes.append(i)
    df['List_Column'] = list_attributes
```

But that's very convoluted. What would be the most efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Option 1**: `groupby().apply(list)`:

```
df.groupby('Name')['Age'].apply(list).to_dict()
# 4.06 ms ± 966 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

**Option 2**: list/dict comprehension

```
{a:list(x) for a,x in df.groupby('Name')['Age']}
# 2.68 ms ± 177 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Output:

```
{'Alex': [10.0],
 'Barbara': [25.0],
 'Bob': [12.0, 72.0],
 'Clarke': [13.0, 13.0],
 'Destiny': [45.0]}
```

Comment: drop duplicates :D

Comment: I appreciate the performance test! This is quite useful for users, and I often wish this information existed more on SO posts :)

Answer (score 1):

A `defaultdict` can work here. `drop_duplicates` first to ensure only unique values get added to the list.

```
from collections import defaultdict

df = df.drop_duplicates()

d = defaultdict(list)
for k,v in zip(df.Name, df.Age):
    d[k].append(v)
#defaultdict(list,
#            {'Alex': [10.0],
#             'Barbara': [25.0],
#             'Bob': [12.0, 72.0],
#             'Clarke': [13.0],
#             'Destiny': [45.0]})
```

---

It's also pretty fast. It will perform much better than the `groupby` in cases where there are many groups with a few unique values per group.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

N=10000
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': np.arange(0,N,1)//10,
                   'Age': np.arange(0,N,1)%100})
df = df.drop_duplicates()

def Alollz(df):
    d = defaultdict(list)
    for k,v in zip(df.Name, df.Age):
        d[k].append(v)
    return d

%timeit Alollz(df)
#3.34 ms ± 7.63 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%timeit {a:list(x) for a,x in df.groupby('Name')['Age']}
#113 ms ± 1.25 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```